# Setting debug=False with Django Rest Framework and React does not work

Tags: reactjs, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have a project on which I use Django Rest Framework and React.
I also use amazon s3 for static and file storage.
The problem is that when I set debug=False in settings, there is nothing except white empyt page. Have you ever met this problem and what did you do to solve ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. In settings.py there is a variable called "STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'". I removed this and all static files uploaded to heroku but my media files run on amazon by the variable called DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).